# Linux Mono + Postsharp + Log4Net = No automated Exception catching

Tags: c#, linux, mono, log4net, postsharp

We are developing a C# project with Monodevelop under Linux.

We have added Log4Net(1.2.11.0), Postsharp (4.1.24.0) and also Postsharp for Log4Net to our project via NuGet.

The following code throws an IndexOutOfRangeException:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using PostSharp;
using PostSharp.Aspects;

[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough]
[Loggable]
class Program
{
    static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        String[] myArray= new String[] { "X" };
        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
            Console.WriteLine (myArray[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, Postsharp doesn't even catch the exception.

We even tried to replace "[Loggable]" with "[LoggableAttribute]", since the Class' name is like that.

Here it is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using PostSharp;
using PostSharp.Aspects;
using System.Collections;

[Serializable]
public class LoggableAttribute : OnExceptionAspect
{

    public override void OnException(MethodExecutionArgs event_args)
    {
        Logging.SetExecutionTime(DateTime.Now);
        Logging.SetParameter("parameters", ParametersToString(event_args));
        Logging.SetParameter("method_name", event_args.Method.Name);
        Logging.SetParameter("class_name", event_args.Instance.GetType().ToString());

        Logging.Error("Error Encountered in " + event_args.Method, event_args.Exception);
    }

    private static String ParametersToString(MethodExecutionArgs event_args)
    {
        String output = "";
        if (event_args.Method.GetParameters() != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < event_args.Method.GetParameters().Length; i++)
            {
                output += String.Format("[{0} = {1}]", event_args.Method.GetParameters()[i].Name, event_args.Method.GetParameters()[i]);
            }
        }
        return output;
    }
}
```

Even a break point within OnException doesn't help. It doesn't get in there.

Comment: 2 important questions: what version of mono is this? does it work in Windows with the .NET framework from Microsoft?

Comment: @knocte It's the mono version 3.2.8. My work mate tried the following under Windows: He removed all the DLLs (Log4Net, Postsharp & Postsharp for Log4Net) and installed them again. It worked fine under Visual Studio 2013. We tried to do the same under Linux & Mono, but still no success.

Comment: ok then it's a mono bug. Try Mono v4.2 first, and if it still doesn't work in this newest version, report a bug here: http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/

Answer (score 1):

PostSharp works fine with mono, I actually use it there for quite some time already. I cannot now test on your mono version (3.2.8 is quite old already), but on 4.0.4 this code runs without problem:

```
[Loggable]
internal class Program {
    private static void Main(string[] args) {
        String[] myArray = new String[] {"X"};
        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
            Console.WriteLine(myArray[i]);
        }
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class LoggableAttribute : OnExceptionAspect {

    public override void OnException(MethodExecutionArgs args) {
        Console.WriteLine("Caught by postsharp: " + args.Exception);
        args.FlowBehavior = FlowBehavior.Continue;
    }
}
```

Outputs "Caught by postsharp: ..." and no exception is thrown. As for log4net, you say yourself that it's not related to your question in any way - your code does not enter block where log4net is used.

So, just update to modern mono version and you'll be fine.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We are still working on it. We have updated monodevlop and also mono itself. According to "mono --version", the version is 4.0.4 now. Monodevelop is running under v5.9.6. Could it be that Monodevelop is still using something old in the background during compilation? It's still not working. We even copied & pasted your code to try.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't use Monodevelop and compiled that in Visual Studio (but ran on mono 4.0.4 under centos 7 - there it's working).

Comment: Well, we did that too, and yes, it's working on VS2013, but we really need it on Monodevelop.

Comment: I guess it's not really compatible with Monodevelop - read here http://doc.postsharp.net/requirements. Their they say "Mono - Not supported, Workaround - Compile on Windows using MSBuild". I also read explicit reply from their developer that MonoDevelop is not supported because of debug symbols format (but that was 3 years ago).